# How to generate multiple header in a ListView?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I've created a ListView that will contain a match results of each nations. Actually the code working pretty well, I can see the results of each match inside the list. But I would optimize the organization of the `List`, in particular each nation contains X match, so I need to separate the nations.

An image example:

[image]

I don't know which control is used in this program, but how you can see there is a static header that contains `Ora - Minuto - Casa - Ospite - 1 Tempo - 2 Tempo - Scelta - Quota`

and after it, there are multiple headers, that contain the nation name: `Austria, Azerbaijan, Belgio, Cina, Danimarca, etc...` against the static header, this nations headers are generated via code. In each nation header there is a list of the match for the specified nation.

Actually I've defined in my Xaml a ListView like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="Match">
         <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="Ora" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" />
                       <GridViewColumn Header="Minuto" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Minute}"/>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="Casa" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Home}"/>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="Ospite" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Away}"/>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="1 Tempo" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Result}"/>
                       <GridViewColumn Header="2 Tempo" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MatchSecondTime}"/>
                </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

I've defined only the static header, I want to know if I can generate dynamic header inside the list and access them as another item. In the past with `vb.net` I've builded my own list control, and managed the same result as header:

```
 Dim Header As New gdkList.ListItem
                Header.Header = True
                ReDim Header.Text(0)
                Header.Text(0).Text = Nation_Name
```

In the net I can't find any open source control and seems that the standard `ListView` does not support this feature. Any experiences about this?

Comment: I never used it, but `ListView.GroupStyle` may be the right direction.

Comment: Syncfusion has a lot of tools like this and they offer community license now.