# How to create dynamic GroupStyle behind code?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've discover the `ListView.GroupStyle` that could solve a problem of multiple headers. Suppose that I've this list in XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="Match">
     <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Time" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}" />
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Minute" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Minute}"/>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Home" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Home}"/>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="Away" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Away}"/>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="1 Time" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Result}"/>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="2 Time" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MatchSecondTime}"/>
            </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
```

Now suppose that I want add multiple GroupStyle as in [this example](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/).
How can I create a GroupStyle behind code?

I actually tried as:

```
Style myStyle = new Style(typeof(GroupItem));
Setter setter = new Setter();
setter.Property = MarginProperty;
setter.Value = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
myStyle.Setters.Add(setter);

Setter setterTemplate = new Setter();
setter.Property = TemplateProperty;
setter.Value = Template;

GroupStyle gs = new GroupStyle();
gs.ContainerStyle = myStyle;
Match.GroupStyle.Add(gs);
```

but I can't set an header name as in the example:

[image]

My goals is create a `GroupStyle` header as displayed in the example `Male, Female`. Someone could show me how?

Comment: You have not given us enough information.  In order to tell you how to do the grouping - you need to tell us your Class that holds the data (like `class User` in your link) and we need to know the enum you want to use to create the group (like `enum SexType` in your link).  Otherwise, we can't help you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966929/how-to-generate-multiple-header-in-a-listview), that you want to group by the Country, very well.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
public class MatchResults{
   public DateTime Time {get;set;}
   public int Minute {get;set;}
   public string Home {get;set;}
   public string Away {get;set;}
   public string 1-Time {get;set;}
   public string 2-Time {get;set;}
   public CountryType Country {get;set}
}
```

then you group by the enum

```
enum CountryType{
  Austria,
  Azerbaijan,
  Belgium,...
}
```

then in your window constructor, after `InitializeComponent()` you will initialize your data items and add them to your list and make them the datasource of the ListView from the XAML (copy most of the code from [the link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)).
Then the last 3 lines of the constructor, you have and replace the Sex argument, with the Country argument:

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Country");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```